# Removing and replacing not working with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Suppose i have this html

`<img src="/anonsurf.php?u=R6zsLPugPcPvtSRshGw3LzhkOBwNbWtv%2FLh%2FVWReMG8a&amp;b=13" data-original="/7/a/0/7a0731cdfa806bdab73f469affc3fb451419064654-640-480-1801-h264.flv-1.jpg">`

I want to remove the `src="/anonsurf.php?u=R6zsLPugPcPvtSRshGw3LzhkOBwNbWtv%2FLh%2FVWReMG8a&amp;b=13"` and then replace `data-original` to make it `scr`

I tried to do it in parts

```
$input = preg_replace('#scr=".*?"#s', '' ,$input); //doesn't work
$input = preg_replace('#data-original=#s', 'scr=' ,$input); //works
```

What's wrong with the regex and how can i put it into a single preg_replace

Comment: You have a simple typo: `scr` in your regex should be `src`: https://regex101.com/r/gJ1pW6/1

Comment: Damn you are 100% right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the typo in

```
$input = preg_replace('#scr=".*?"#s', '' ,$input); //doesn't work
```

be responsible? Should it be:

```
$input = preg_replace('#src=".*?"#s', '' ,$input); //doesn't work
```

Haven't tested it, but that would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
$input = preg_replace('#src=".*?data-original=#s', 'src="' ,$input);
```